# Get instance of child class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have a base abstract class "BaseEngine" and a child class "Engine : BaseEngine".

The Engine has a public property of type Engine called "Instance":

```
public Engine Instance
{ get; set; }
```

I want to get this Instance from the BaseEngine. I already tried this:

```
public abstract BaseEngine<T> where T : class
{
    public T Instance { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public Engine : BaseEngine<Engine>
```

but it creates recursion.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you!

UPDATE

I have lots of classes derived from BaseEngine class. Each child class have methods which do practically the same thing. I was trying to move those methods to the base class to change less code in case of a changing. I will try to find another way to do this, because what I asked cannot be done. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: You need to explain a little more what you are trying to do. What you are describing can not be done as-is, imagine it with other terms and it is easier to see, if you had `Shape` and `Square` you are trying to reference `Square` from inside the `Shape` function. If you tell us what you are trying to accomplish [we can help you solve that problem instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is all very strange.

Comment: Parent classes should not have to know details about implementing types, this smells bad.

Comment: Why does your base class need to know about the derived class? The base class should know nothing about the derived classes as it generally indicates a code smell.

Comment: What do you mean by "it creates recursion"?

Comment: This is completely pointless - there's no useful way to set that property without knowing which child type it is anyway. Basically: what advantage do you ever gain by having a variable of type `BaseEngine<Engine>` instead of directly `Engine`?

Comment: From your update, it looks like you want override-able functions, [see Colin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19030270/80274).

Comment: The problem here is that there's really no useful application for this I can see. If you had a method, say `ConnectAnotherEngine(TEngine engine)`, the implementation of that method could only use methods from whatever the bound of `T` is. At that point you might as well just directly use the bound. Analogously, if you had a base class method `TEngine ReturnThis()`, there's no way to actually implement it correctly without requiring something bizarre, or a cast. It would make limited sense if you just wanted to declare abstract methods like that, in which case your construct is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know much about what you are trying to do you should be aware that if you have an instance of `Engine`, then the code in the `BaseEngine` still has an `Engine` even if it doesn't know that. It shouldn't know what the derived class is in any event as that would be a code smell.

However, if you need to access functions in Engine from the base class you can create the base class as being `abstract` and create `abstract` functions (that is, functions with no implementation) in the base class and have the derived class implement them.

Or you could create `virtual` functions and have the derived class `override` them which can then replace or add additional functionality.

This would generally be the recommended way of having a base class access functionality in a derived class.

For example:

```
public abstract class BaseEngine
{
  public void DoStuff()
  {
    // Do some things here
    DoDerivedStuff();
    // Do some other things here
  }

  protected abstract void DoDerivedStuff();

  public virtual void DoOverridableStuff()
  {
    // Do stuff in here.
  }
}

public class Engine : BaseEngine
{
   protected override void DoDerivedStuff()
   {
     // Do stuff here that is particular to this derived type.
   }

   public override void DoOverridableStuff()
   {
      // Do additional stuff for the Engine class if necessary
      base.DoOverridableStuff(); // You can omit this if you don't 
                                 // want to do what the base is doing.
      // Do more stuff for the engine class if necessary
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have the `Instance` property be typed to child class, you need to return `BaseEngine` instead but you can return a instance of `Engine` in that property, the caller will just need to cast it if need be.

```
public abstract class BaseEngine
{
    public BaseEngine Instance {get; private set;}
}

public class FarrariEngine : BaseEngine
{
    public FarrariEngine()
    {
        this.Instance = this; //This line is VERY weird to me.
    }
}

public class LawnmowerEngine : BaseEngine
{
    public LawnmowerEngine ()
    {
        this.Instance = this;
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static Main(string[] args)
    {
        var farrari = new FarrariEngine();
        Engine currentEngine = farrari.Instance. //Works
        FarrariEngine currentFarrariEngine = (FarrariEngine)farrari.Instance. //Also works.

        var lawnMower = new LawnmowerEngine();
        Engine currentEngine = lawnMower.Instance. //Works
        LawnmowerEngine currentLawnmowerEngine = (LawnmowerEngine)lawnMower.Instance. //Also works.
    }
}
```

This is common in the .NET framework, look at the children of [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx). Things like `GetResponse()` all return [the](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) [base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.filewebrequest.getresponse.aspx) [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx).

However it is very odd that you have a property that returns a type of the parent class (especially called `Instance`), was the property supposed to be static and you are trying to do the singleton pattern?

Comment: "This is common in the .NET framework" this is not a good rationale. Vast swathes of the .NET framework predate generics, and because C# uses reification and not type erasure, there's no way to retrofit existing classes to use them. A from-scratch implementation of that API could easily use the construct the OP has, and it would actually make perfect sense.

Comment: Actually it wouldn't even be a construct the OP has. `interface Request<TResponse> where TResponse : Response { TResponse {get;} }` is a perfectly good nonrecursive use of generics.